# CSS Sticky - How to sticky aside to fill available height?

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

I want to create grid layout and I want to aside to be sticky to `top: 0` and fill all remaining height e.g. 100% of height and when I scroll down I need to change aside height to 100% subtract footers height. It's can be done without JS?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "aside content"
    "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 20rem 1fr;
}

aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background-color: red;

}
nav {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
main {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: green;
  height: 150vh;
}
footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 10rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <aside>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav></aside>
  <main>Content</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want. an element that fill the remaining height cannot be sticky

Comment: When user not see footer I want to have nav to 100% of remaining height and when user scrolls down to footer nav needs to have 100% - footers height, It's possible or am I thinking wrong ?

Comment: 100% of users window not viewport height

Comment: Can you please be more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `height:100%` with `min-height:100vh`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "aside content"
    "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 20rem 1fr;
}

aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background-color: red;

}
nav {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  
  min-height:100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}
main {
  grid-area: content;
  background-color: green;
  height: 150vh;
}
footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 10rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <aside>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav></aside>
  <main>Content</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ;) That's exactly what I was looking for